# fatal error: helloworld.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c, macos, terminal, compiler-errors, archlinux

I'm completely new to programming, and it's my first time learning C. I'm trying to run the Hello World program. I'm using Utm, Arch Linux to run it however I'm getting this error.

`[root@alarm ~]# gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld`

`cc1: fatal error: helloworld.c: No such file or directory compilation terminated.`

On the UTM, my shared directory is "ArchLinuxShared" and I entered it in my text editor and saved it as “helloworld.c”. I get that error when I try to access it from the Linux bash window and compile it. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: You did not save the file in your home directory which is where you now try to compile the program. Do `cd` to the `ArchLinuxShared` directory and then rerun the compilation command

Comment: Btw, are you logged in as `root`? If so, why?

Comment: do the `ls -l` and see if you have your `.c` there

Comment: @TedLyngmo It says "bash: cd: ArchLinuxShared: No such file or directory". That is the username and password, my professor says that's just how its set up.

Comment: @gulpr it doesn't show anything.

Comment: then you are in the wrong directory. Find it `find  / -name "helloworld.c"`

Comment: @gulpr I had it in the wrong directory. Thank you!